# I have a question on the '\v' escape character?

Tags: python, escaping, character

the \v escape character is supposed to be for a 'vertical tab', but when i was trying to print a \v it printed a  character, why is this happening?, is this the purpose of the '\v' character.

here is my python code

```
print("hello world\v bye world")
```

my output

```
hello world bye world
```

here is another example of my problem
[Error-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL3eD.png)
[Error-Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ8fY.png)
this problem occurs with '\a' too ↑↑↑

Thanks for your help!

Comment: VT ('\v') works as expected in 3.10.4. It may be different in earlier versions. Also worth mentioning that there's pretty much no use nowadays for VT unless you're sending output to a line printer

Comment: `\v` represents a particular ASCII value, that's all. How any particular device  chooses to *display* that character is independent of Python.

Comment: In iTerm2, both `\v` and `\f` appear to be treated equivalently: advance the cursor to the next line without moving it back to the first column. Presumably, some devices used to allow vertical tab stops for moving down the page in the same way horizontal tab stops allowed for moving across the page.